# Connect to MSN Messenger from ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, msn-messenger

Has anyone connected to MSN Messenger from an ASP.NET page? We found this component: http://www.xihsolutions.net/dotmsn/, but it works only for desktop applications and we couldn't make it work in our web site.

Are there any working solutions either with the above component or with another component?

Answer (score 2):

Yep -> [Windows Live Services](http://dev.live.com/). More specifically, the [Messenger service](http://dev.live.com/messenger/) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb936682.aspx) is the doco to embed the IM Control into your site.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The client wants an integrated experience (i.e. to login from our site), but we might change it if we don't find another way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that that code is now in Google Code and is now called [MSNP-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/). I have used it in a Windows Forms Application with success. If you want to call it from the web you could create a web service that is logged into an account and can send messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened port 1863 (= the port messenger uses) in the firewall/router/proxy/... ?